# Different versions of the Robertson-Walker Metric

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, space-expansion

One form of the Robertson-Walker metric is $$ds^2 = c^2dt^2 - a(t)^2[d\chi^2+ S_k(\chi)^2(d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta ~d\phi^2)]\tag{1}$$
$$\\$$

Considering curvature, where k = 0 , +1, -1 for flat, positive and negative curvatures respectively, then: $$S_k(\chi) = \begin{cases}R\sin(\chi/R)~~~~~~(k=+1)\\\chi~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(k=0)\\R\sinh(\chi/R)~~~~(k=-1)\end{cases}$$
$$\\$$

But another form of this metric is $$ds^2=c^2dt^2 - a(t)^2\left[\frac{dr^2}{1-kr^2} + r^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2~d\phi^2)\right]\tag{2}$$
$$\\$$

How does one go from $(1)$ to $(2)$? (or vice versa) I get that this is due to a switch of choice of coordinates, from radial to co-moving radial, I think? But how can it be shown that they represent the same metric?

Comment: You should use another symbol for the radial coordinate in one of these metrics: $r$ and $\tilde{r}$ for example, since they aren't the same.  In the first metric, it is usually $\chi$ instead of $r$.

Comment: Also, consider adding a number to each of your equations, using the LaTeX command \tag{number}.  It would help the discussion and answers to come.

Comment: @Cham: Yes I will consider those things and I have edited my post accordingly. That being said, does it improve the probability of you answering my post? Since no one else would.

Comment: Have you tried the coordinate transformation $r=S_k(\chi)$?

Comment: Also, $(2)$ needs to have $k$ replace by $k/R^2$ in order to make sense dimensionally.

Comment: @mmeent, $r$ in (2) doesn't have any units (the scale factor $a(t)$ do have units).  So this metric doesn't need $k / R^2$.  This version is perfectly standard.  I would use $c = 1$, though.  Also, $\chi$ shouldn't have any units.  The constant $R$ shouldn't be there.

Comment: For  $r\rightarrow Rsin\left( \dfrac{\lambda }{R}\right) $ dr=....,in equation 2 and k =1 you get equation 1

Comment: @mmeent: I did see it with $k/R^2$ in another text and was about to ask about that as well but omitted it at the risk of making the question too long. But since you mentioned it, and with the additional input from Cham, I guess I got two birds in one stone...just perfect, Tnx for all comments and answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understood in my cosmology course, you simply normalize the metric $(1)$ by taking
\begin{equation}
\chi(r)=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-kr^2}}\ \mathrm{d}r\tag{int}
\end{equation}
This integral has 3 different solutions based on the value of $k$ which is your curvature
\begin{equation}
\chi(r)=\left\{\begin{aligned}
&\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\sin^{-1}\left(r\sqrt{k}\right)&k>0\\
&r&k=0\\
&\frac{1}{\sqrt{|k|}}\sinh^{-1}\left(r\sqrt{|k|}\right)&k<0
\end{aligned}\right.\tag{sol}
\end{equation}
Through inversion of $(\mathrm{sol})$ you get your $S_k(\chi)$ function, which gives your $r$
\begin{equation}
r(\chi)=S_k(\chi)=\left\{\begin{aligned}
&\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\sin\left(\chi\sqrt{k}\right)&k>0\\
&\chi&k=0\\
&\frac{1}{\sqrt{|k|}}\sinh\left(\chi\sqrt{|k|}\right)&k<0
\end{aligned}\right.\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Now, writing our differential we get
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{d}\chi^2&=\frac{1}{1-kr^2}\mathrm{d}r^2\\\hfill\\
r^2&\left(\mathrm{d}\theta^2+\sin^2(\theta)\mathrm{d}\phi^2\right)=S_k^2(\chi)\left(\mathrm{d}\theta^2+\sin^2(\theta)\mathrm{d}\phi^2\right)
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}
And there you are, it should be what you are searching for if I got the question correctly